# detect if image is a face not if faces exist inside an image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, classification

I am using a yolov5 nn that is tracking heads and want to use these heads to discover the age and gender of these heads. To do this I must make sure that we are capturing the side of the head that shows the face. So I am trying to crop these heads and detect whether these head crops can also be used as face crops. The issue I am facing is that all face recognition techniques I can find look for faces within an image rather is an image of a face. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

```
def get_age_gender(frame):
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.show()
    resultImg, faceBoxes = highlightFace(faceNet, frame)
    print(faceBoxes)
    plt.imshow(resultImg)
    plt.show()

    for faceBox in faceBoxes:
        face = frame[max(0, faceBox[1] - padding):
                     min(faceBox[3] + padding, frame.shape[0] - 1), max(0, faceBox[0] - padding)
                                                                    :min(faceBox[2] + padding, frame.shape[1] - 1)]
        #if face.shape
        if face.shape[0] == 0 or face.shape[1] == 0:
            break
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, (227, 227), MODEL_MEAN_VALUES, swapRB=False)
        genderNet.setInput(blob)
        genderPreds = genderNet.forward()
        gender = genderList[genderPreds[0].argmax()]
        print(f'Gender: {gender}')

        ageNet.setInput(blob)
        agePreds = ageNet.forward()
        age = ageList[agePreds[0].argmax()]
        print(f'Age: {age[1:-1]} years')
        return age, gender

    return '0', 'gender'

frame = cv2.imread(f'output/Capture2.JPG')
get_age_gender(frame)
```

[image]

Comment: i dont know. maybe try a modal that detects and identifies where the face is and then check wether the size of face is appropriate enough for you to say that it is a pic of a face

Comment: the task is called "classification". *does a picture belong to a certain class or not* (dogs, cars, faces).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `face_alignment` library for PyTorch.

Installation - `pip install face_alignment`

Usage -

```
import face_alignment 

fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment.LandmarksType._2D, flip_input=False)
landmarks = fa.get_landmarks_from_image(IMAGE)

if landmarks is None:
   print(f'No faces detected')
else:
   print(f'Faces were detected')
```

You use this method to generate the landmarks for the image. If no faces were detected, the landmarks would be set to `None` which you can subsequently use to check whether your images contain any faces or not.